# Is full VR immersion plausible?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, virtual-reality

First, let me define what I mean by "full VR immersion". A helmet or headwear that covers or plugs into the brain, allowing them to control a virtual self or physical thing (such as a robot) as well as they would control their own body, without also moving their own body. A few pieces of media that have something similar to help see what I'm envisioning is "the matrix" and "Sword Art Online". What this technology might be used for:

- Military training
- Mecha Piloting
- Entertainment

Is such a thing plausible in a science-based setting?

Comment: *Sword Art Online* does a pretty good job of describing the science behind the NerveGear-- it disrupts the signals between your brain and your body, it uses microwaves, etc.  More science-based than *that* and you run the risk of boring all but the most scientifically-minded readers.

Comment: You can also check out the graphic novel *Surrogates* for possible non-entertainment-based applications of this kind of technology.

Comment: I would argue that SAO description was woefully underdeveloped and the topic was practically hand-waved and a LOT more description would be in order, not less.

Comment: plausible at what tech level?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes but...**

You would need to install quite a lot of ports on the head of a person, because You need to connect directly to a lot of nerves, both on the facial side (eyes, nose, everything in mouth) and at the base of the skull, to the spinal cord.

THEN You would need a lot of work to decode that person's signalling scheme. Unfortunately, it seems our brains dont use the same 'coding pages' if you will - for example, the information about blue color is encoded by a different signal in my brain and in yours.

THEN You would somehow need to take over control of stuff that our conscious brain oversees or directly controls - You dont want muscles controlling the bladder suddenly letting go.

Unfortunately, this technology is much farther than we would like.

Comment: Suppose you used something like the mesh that attached itself to peoples entire brains in the book "Tripods", would this be enough of a connection assuming you directly connected it to a persons nerves? Also, would determining people who could use based on a range of coding pages (such that all pilots store information in a similar way) possible?

Comment: Interestingly i both don't understand your last sentence, "Unfortunately, this technology is much farther than we would like." and disagree with it. If you meant "farther along" is disagree with that (we are much farther from that than from fusion, and that is 40 years away; always), and if you meant "farther away" i disagree too, but this time with the "unfortunately" - nothing net good would come of the tech for completely isolating humans from the world.

Comment: @bukwyrm You are free to disagee, present Your arguments and/or evidence and/or propose Your own answer whenever You wish ; )

Comment: @user49634 Regarding the mesh - i don't know that book, but from Your description, my feeling is that such a mesh would be even more problematic with our current technology. This a kind of thing which could be done maybe with nanobots if anything.
Regarding code pages - since we have really no idea, we have not deciphered even one brain yet, I think You are safe to assume that this is a case in Your world and stay within range of speculative SF.

Comment: @Empischon : The Tripods is a series of books & a BBC TV series (last aired sometime in the 80's iirc), the mesh in question would be nothing more than a high tech version of the chips dropped into people brains to allow them to control a computer cursor & regain some vision despite the optic nerve being damaged, perfectly solid real world science at its core & already seeing some limited real world use, no nanobots required. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_(TV_series)

Comment: @Empischon : "not deciphered even one brain yet" you don't need to (not fully), the brains very adaptable, it's often a matter of training it to use the new implant, you generally appear to only need to drop it in broadly the right region of the brain followed by a period of physical therapy style training.

Answer (score 3):

Easy peasy. Basically, you want lucid dreaming with an I/O interface.

(Note: If I can dodge work enough I will try to find the New Scientist sources for this to add to the answer later, but I have read articles on all these three points recently)

You simply need to rig up a brain interface into the optic nerve. There is recent technology that can show a grainy but identifiable image of what someone is looking at simply by measuring brain waves; that gives you the output part.

The input part you'll have to handwave, but it's not too much of a stretch to come up with something that can trigger specific images.

As for the immobile part, that's exactly what the body does naturally during REM dream sleep. So simply plug in your I/O helmet, trigger the body's natural REM state to immobilise your muscles, boot up the lucid dream for the world you want, and voila!

This addresses the comments I've seen here a few times - about the difficulty of immobilising muscles, and about fast/fine control; I have incredibly vivid, occasionally lucid and almost always sci-fi dystopian dreams, and I can confirm that I can walk, run, jump, fly, fight, drive vehicles, fly planes etc etc etc and all without falling out of bed, and I'm pretty sure everyone else here can too :)

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely, to outright impossible.

Preramble: The retina of the eyes actually is part of your central nervous system, so this is not about 'just' interdicting the central-nervous system (CNS) /peripheral-nervous system PNS switchover (which in itself is not like a plug-in situation)

Sometime in the future, we will be able to cut a small peripheral nerve (say part of one finger) and both fake the incoming information and use the outgoing information in a way that will approach the natural usage of this sense/motor pathway. This would lead to better prosthetics.
We can also 'listen' in on a nerve-fibre without cutting it, and decode the signal, so we might be able to steer something without levers, just by having it listen in on nervous impulses directed to some muscle groups. Anesthesising those msucles would mean we do not even move all the while. 
Completely hijacking a nerve fibre without cutting it or otherwise physically interacting with it is, and will always be impossible, though. The fibres are far to small and tightly packed to achieve the kind of electrical field strength neccessary by remote means. TMS (Transcranial magnetic stimulation) currently can scramble signals in **one** "tight" spot of about one inch diameter - this still is several orders of magnitude too many cells to achieve anything but the most general effects. MRI (Magnetic Resonance Imaging aka the Tube) can, in very specific setups, sample down to a cubic millimetre (that's reading, not writing) - which also is several orders of magnitude too many cells.

Both of those methods only take care of the electrical side of nerve interaction - this will only do for peripheral nerves - centrally there is alot of chemistry involved, too. No remote sampling will give you the current concentration of transmitters and hormones present at specific synapses on specific neurons (remember: the neurons are not key here, it is their connections, the synapses, that do the magic - and there are sometimes hundreds of those to every neuron.

To sum up: This level of VR-immersion would require contact to every nerve-fibre involved - Handwavium-Nanobots are a must, or you remove the brain from the cranium - both techniques would not achieve full immersion either as a lot of dependencies are (not exactly hardwired, but let's say firmware-d) to the senses - see several psychiatric cases where people no longer believed that their arm actually belonged to them -  sense of self is a very precarious thing, and not remotely well understood (on that note: it's so badly understood right now, that you might as well handwave a particular brain area (posterior parietal would be a good place to start) that governed self-image and make it both easy to manipulate and easy to reset - then you could exclude the real sensory input/output, and include some synthetic i/o. Thereby the whole technical impossibility of realistically shaping nervous i/o would vanish because whatever was presented would 'feel' natural - the aspect of making sense of that i/o would still remain, though. Imagine feeling a sormth in your flavjet (entirely normal) but (inexplicably to you) having no idea where and what that is, how to respond and --oops, you died.

The brain is very pliable, though: Supposing the input/output was loosely resembling the way it works in usual humans, it might be possible to raise a child (or its brain) from foetal stages onwards in a synthetic environment, thereby giving the brain enough time to grow into understanding and reliably interacting with that i/o.

Comment: so it would have to be an aparatus that connected to most if not all the neurons in a persons brain, at birth, and the child would have to be raised in such a way that they would be able to use this device to interface with things?

Comment: @user49634: it would not even need to connect to every single neuron. All the points where peripheral nerves contact the central neurons (plus the optic nerve and (if required) the nasal nerve) would suffice. Suffice both to make it possible theoretically and impossible practically... To interface with the rest of the neurons would give you access to moods, thoughts, memories...

Comment: @user49634: re the child-raising: also consider the phenomenon of phantom limbs/pain in respect to having a brain interface with a removable i/o-generating entity such as a mecha - this is one of the problems where interfacing with that elusive self-image center could come in handy.

Comment: "The retina of the eyes actually is part of your central nervous system" technically true, but still afaik it's only a couple of nerves, so placing a few gates shouldn't be more difficult than placing those gates in the spinal cord.

Comment: I'll just leave this here then https://www.technologyreview.com/s/511466/microchip-restores-vision/ I don't think co-opting the signals passing through the optic nerve is really as hard as you seem to be suggesting, the linked article shows that pretty conclusively I think.

Comment: Did the question change since you answered because there seems to be a lot of focus (almost off topic even) on immersion & "sense of self" that I don't see the question asking for?

Comment: @Pelinore : OP asked for "virtual self" which i took to mean self, but virtual, so...   ----- and about that study: They patched the retina, did not interact with the optic nerve directly. huge difference.

Comment: The retina IS an interface, it's build to transcribe and translate 2D structured data. Press the side of your eyeball - pretty colors in the corresponding hemisphere - that's not new tech.

Comment: @Empischon: exactly, it's just like placing 'gates' in the spinal cord, because that too is part of the CNS

Answer (score 0):

without moving their own body is the tricky part, that requires severing the signals to the body which is not something down easily or lightly. or course sticking them in a big sensory dep tank and letting them move is an option.

Eventually we will be able to do what you want, but we are talking the level of printing a body from scratch levels of tech. A level of tech where a severed spine is as easy to deal with as getting a tattoo today.

You would have to spend weeks of not months just having your synaptic pattern mapped by an AI just so the inputs can match what your body already does. It is possible this could be done while you go about your everyday life however. This in and of itself could have utility in diagnosing sensory and other abnormalities, it is possible such deep interaction with an AI might become commonplace, It has already been proposed as as way to integrate humans and computer most successfully.

Comment: "that requires severing the signals to the body which is not something down easily or lightly" : I'm not so sure about that, there have been successes with embedding chips to bridge the gap in damaged neural tissue of the optic nerve which restored some limited vision, I could see something like that implanted in the spinal column so you can just switch traffic from the spinal column below it to the outputs desired then back again when done. but it's far more likely you'd induce sleep paralysis instead (you do that yourself every night perfectly naturally).

Comment: for the implant to stop signals going to the body the spine has to be severed, hence my statement.

Comment: severed or damaged optic nerves have effectively been bridged or replaced, hence my comment.

Comment: And there is a big difference between restoring some function to a damaged nerve then severing the spine on purpose so you can play videogames.

Comment: and there is a big difference between can "we do this now" & "Is such a thing plausible in a science-based setting" which is the actual question.

Comment: As I said though I'd go for induced sleep-paralysis (Google it if you don't know what this is) to prevent movement while in the virtual environment, severing the spine (though plausible) isn't the only option.

Answer (score 0):

[Functional MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_magnetic_resonance_imaging) allows noninvasive measurement and characterization of brain activity.  With high resolution one could map and characterize brain activity corresponding to various voluntary activities.  This is not science fiction; described here (in 2012) is a device that uses brain fMRI to generate letters and spell words.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982212005751

So controlling something with your mind noninvasively: yes.

What about feedback directly to your brain.  This could be accomplished with [transcranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation).  Magnetic fields are used to produce current in a nerve, replicating the effect of that nerve firing.  I googled to see if this technique had ever produced hallucinations in a person (as one would expect if a sensory nerve were stimulated in absence of inputs from the sensory organ).  These folks propose that ball lightning is a product of exactly this phenomenon, occurring naturally.  !
https://www.technologyreview.com/s/418887/magnetically-induced-hallucinations-explain-ball-lightning-say-physicists/

So efferent and afferent nerve control is possible with near future precise magnetic technology.

The problem then is moving the remote without moving your body.  That can be accomplished with mid 1900s technology.  Paralytics are routinely used to prevent muscular motion in persons on a ventilator because of illness or surgery. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromuscular-blocking_drug
It is upsetting to be paralyzed while not sedated as occasionally happens by accident.  You can be paralyzed, awake, and feel pain.  For purposes of the scenario in the OP I think paralytics (and respiratory support with a ventilator - you are paralyzed!) would serve.

Comment: MRI is able to detect variations in the usage of whole swaths of neurons, en bloc. You can deduce something from that, just as one might be able, just from seeing the flickering reflection on a wall, to decide whether someone is playing a)MarioCart or b)Halo. Just the flickering, no options to choose from, no way to know: game?, fire?, TV?, LED?... Same with MRI - is she thinking about a,b or c? easy. What's she thinking? impossible. TMS is cool, but to get the currents focussed on the scale of single neurons, you need magnetic fluxes that would, to use a technical term, eff your shit up.

Comment: @bukwyrm: if fMRI can currently distinguish between thinking of c and thinking of g, further precision seems to me not so incredible.  Re improvements: consider the resolution differences of MRI images between 1988 and 2018.

Comment: @Wilk: There will be improvement. Squids might help alleviate the need for ever stronger magnets, new algorithms will whittle down on the scale. But the main point is: This works for a set of decisions: Have a VR-simulated 747 with all its knobs and levers - i'll give you in 20 years one might possibly distinguish between all those settings - does she switch knob 328 to setting 10 or 11? - but it would still be much easier to just have someone don a VR-glove and do it that way. And it'd still be useless if she thought about flowers = not part of the set -> Nearest knob is pressed

Comment: "These folks propose that ball lightning is a product of exactly this phenomenon" : Ball lightning is a real physical phenomena not a hallucination, hallucinations don't injure people or set fire to buildings (all things ball lightning has done) & can't be photographed or videoed (which ball lightning has been). So this does make me wonder about (& perhaps query) the reliability of anything else "these folks" have to say?

Comment: You don't need paralytics in order to prevent movement: just replicate the natural effect of sleep paralysis. If you're interfacing with the brain in a sophisticated enough manner to create a realistic controlled hallucination, which this type of VR essentially is, then inducing sleep paralysis should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> control a virtual self or physical thing (such as a robot) as well as
>   they would control their own body, **without also moving** their own body

To what extent do you expect the user's physical body to be immobile? There are fiction similar to SAO (users going into full VR) where the immersion is done by submerging into basically a vat of gel, which absorbs the actual motion and uses sensors to translate it into actions of the in-game avatar. This imho may be a far easier approach than completely cutting off motor signals as in SAO.

Basically, the user would also wear a helmet to help with the sensory aspects (vision, sound, maybe even smell if we have a reliable way to generate 'smell palettes'). The gel solution he is immersed in - and the surrounding tank which has tons of sensors - allow for some motion that is translated into VR space.

However, while I think it could be a promising start for slow motion sync of movements; I find it doubtful that it can simulate complex fast actions (dance, parkour etc.) though simpler ones (running, jumping) may just be a case of having the actual movement in RL dampened by gel and able to infer the right changes in VR space.

Another advantage of 'gel immersion' in atleast one of the stories, is that its also used to deal with waste matter - the body can excrete sweat, urine or w/e and the tank's filtration system takes care of keeping a hygienic environment.

Answer (score -1):

Using some logic from Ghosts of Onyx from the Halo series, a rebel general manages to attach a disruption collar to a set of spartan armor which halts all commands to the suit basically rendering them immobile.  Perhaps the same could be applied.

What I would propose is a motorized suit that is linked to the helmet.  This product is, unfortuantely, less of just a helmet and instead a fully enclosed, articulated and motorized suit.  It would have to be fully enclosed in order to create the immersion necessary to feel more in the simulation.  The suit would take data from both the user and the simulation.  It would allow freedom of movement within the limitation of the simulation.  The suit would instead translate interactions by using the motors (or hydraulics or any method of artificial locomotion).  An example would be walking into a wall.  the suit would limit the range of motion the user has at the moment they interact with the object.  Another, more dynamic example would be wrestling with an opponent stronger than the user.  The suit would simulate this by actively resisting or even moving the body in the same direction as the simulation dictates the opponent would push it.

To increase immersion, the inside of the suit could be lined with numerous small hydraulic pistons on the inside, nothing dangerous or large but just enough to jab someone inside.  For example, walking into a table edge would cause 1 or a set of the pistons to strike you at or near that location causing a real sensation of discomfort.  It would help discourage the user from making the same mistake as the simulation now contains real life consequences.

To help with climate or other sensory inputs, a mesh could be worn beneath said suit that can produce both heat and cold sensations.  Depending on the intricacy of the suit being worn, it could simulate temperatures in specific places only.  This would only apply to things like the user sticking their hand into a fire in the simulation or taking a plunge into water.

> they would control their own body, without also moving their own body.

This part would be difficult with this suggestion as it would require a range of motion.  Though perhaps creating some sort of suspension device attached to a suit would allow this.

Though, if I may add some pros and cons to the suspended suit suggestion

**PROS**

- allow for non invasive feedback from the system in terms of trauma or resistance
- allow unmodified personnel access to the simulator
- reduce the amount of time needed for tedious tasks (cleaning ports, maintaining ports)
- reduce need for surgeries to maintain any implants (should be none with this method or minimal)
- total system failure or feedback would most likely not kill the user (feedback levels allowing of course)

**CONS**

- requires an area for range of motion
- Possible suspension devices hampering motion
- increased device maintenance
- requires a fully enclosed, possibly air tight helmet for full VR immersion (may lead to suffocation for failures)

Edited for clarity.

Comment: I have no idea what you are proposing. It sounds like a suit that induces paraplegy(how?), and which is suspended by ropes(?) ? Please expand a bit on the mechanism by which a user would use such a device to move a mecha or similar.

Comment: And how excatly this mesh would block the signals in the selected nerves in the first place? One cannot hand-weave this and stay within science-based realm.

Comment: All, I have attempted to clarify my idea.  I had thought I put a simple explanation in but it was my mind playing tricks on me.  Thanks for the feedback.